Are WebSocket 'message' listeners removed automatically when connection closed or the socket is nullified?
I'm using
  socket.close(3001, "Reason: PopUp Closed");
  socket = null;

to cut a websocket connection.
Will its event listeners, that I've created like this, be automatically removed?
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("Message from server ", event.data);
});

Couldn't find an answer on MDN nor anywhere.

The events will probably still exist until the socket gets garbage collected if you don't explicitly remove them first

@NickSlash the eventListener callback only contain some minor object mutation logic. Even if it gets deleted after a long while, it doesn't affect my app performance. But my main concern is, after the WS is nullified, its listener callbacks not being freed from memory at all.
